# Iterator doesn't have a method to getNextElement directly without moving cursor

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Why is there no method to get an element directly without iterating through it?

I have looked for an answer and found some copy-pasted answer like this:

> It can be implemented on top of current Iterator interface but since its use will be rare, it doesn't make sense to include it in the interface that everyone has to implement.

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Because it's, err, an iterator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection Interface extends "Iterable".So all the implementations will have to use iterator. To get an Element in map directly,we can use map.get(Key). To get an element in List we can use index. As List implements RandaomAccess Interface its easy to get an element directly using key. But in Set we cant get an element directly. The point I am trying to make is all the implementations are different but one thing is common in all the implementations we need to go through the objects inside a collection .this job is done by Iterator.

Now JAVA promotes Object Oriented programming so using iterator we can use object(Iterator instance) and call the methods hasNext() to first check if element present.It imposes a limit of iteration restriction. Then using next() we will get the next element. So hasNext() imposes a nullCheck also.

In a nutshell this promotes Object oriented concept and a flexible abstarction to be used by different implementations.

Answer (score -1):

> Iterator don't have a method to getNextElement() directly without
>   moving cursor ?

To explain this, I have taken the below code of `Iterator`'s `next()` method taken from `AbstractList` (which implements `Iterator` interface).

```
public E next() {
      try {
          //some code
          return next;
       } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
           //some code
           throw new NoSuchElementException();
     }
}
```

So, now if you look at the above code, you will get the answer i.e., because if you try to invoke the `getNextElement()` (or `next()` which is equivalent) directly on `Iterator` without knowing the index, will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (will be wrapped by `NoSuchElementException`). So to avoid this, we will first check that the next element (index) is available (using `hasNext()`) and then try to retrieve the element from the collection.

Also, you need to note that the **Iterator is a design pattern** in which an iterator is used to traverse a container (collection) and access the container's elements, you can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern). In other words, Iterators provide you the convenient methods for looping through the collection without worrying about the underlying collection implementation.